# what is main different between FHIR Client & FHIR server

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I have an EMR system its develop using java & oracle database now I want to integrate FHIR server in my system environment and want to share my EMR data to another system. I want to use the HAPI library to integrate FHIR in my system. But I am some confusion about implementation process flow like as different between FHIR client & FHIR server, how to map EMR data to FHIR Resource for mapping data is there any tools? what is the architecture tire? Is FHIR Client and FHIR Server has stayed in the same tire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A client is a system that invokes operations (search, read, create, update, delete, etc.) on a server.  A server is a system that controls data for one or more resources and can respond to operation invocations from an authorized client.  If you're using HAPI, you'll need to write code to map between your internal data model and the FHIR objects that will be used to exchange your data with other FHIR systems.

Comment: do you provide any process flow  diagram link & any link about architecture tire and layer between  my EMR system to FHIR System to another FHIR or EMR system

Comment: From FHIR's perspective the architecture between your internal persistence layer and the FHIR interface is undefined - it can be incorporated directly, handled with a mapping layer, or even handled by a separate system.  The FHIR-to-FHIR interfaces are simple RESTful calls.